# WebScraping a web forms application. Trying to simulate a post request to download a file

Tags: asp.net, webforms, web-scraping

I am trying to make a post request from c# code to a web page that uses asp.net  Web Forms view page. I tacked down using chrome dev tools to see what is sent when i click a button an the file is downloaded to my pc and tried to do it in c#.
I dont know web forms but i read that the winforms post request has to include the `__ViewState` hidden field in the request body so i tried that but got an `exception: "Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long."`

```
                       var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        {"ctl00$txtSearchProduct", ""},
                        {"ctl00$TextArea", ""},
                        {"ctl00$MainContent$chain", "7290058179503"}, //company id
                        {"ctl00$MainContent$subChain", "-1"},
                        {"ctl00$MainContent$branch", "-1"},
                        {"ctl00$MainContent$txtDate", ""},
                        {"ctl00$MainContent$fileType", "all"},
                        {"__EVENTTARGET", fileParam},
                        {"__EVENTARGUMENT", ""},
                        {"__LASTFOCUS", ""},
                        {"__VIEWSTATE", viewState},
                    };

                    //exception here
                    var content2 = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

                    var response = await client.PostAsync(BaseUrl, content2);
```